# Can somebody translate this ASM instruction code for Cortex M7?

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly, cortex-m

`" mrs %0, ipsr " : "=r" (reg_tmp)`

I need to translate this ASM code out-of-curiosity, it is for ARMV7 specifically cortex-M7 executing in privileged mode. I know MRS instruction is move from special register (the IPSR sub-register/bitfield of PSR here) to gen-purpose register. But I don't understand this part : "=r" (reg_tmp) somehow. Also what does the %0 means here?

I have to be honest I have little idea about ASM code, so please take it in mind. :)

ASM code generate out of this is:

```
push {r4}
mrs r3,ipsr
mov r4,r3
mov r3,r4
mov r0,r3
pop {r4}
bx  r14
```

Can this be optimized to:

```
push {r4}
mrs r0,ipsr
pop {r4}
bx  r14
```

Comment: You could consult the documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#OutputOperands

Comment: `%0` is the first (and in this case only) argument to the inline assembly block. The `=r` means it's an output in a general purpose register the compiler is free to choose and should map to the variable `reg_tmp`.

Comment: Thanks Jester, I think I need to have a look at inline assembly properly.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/extensions-to-the-c-language-family/how-to-use-inline-assembly-language-in-c-code.html#basic-asm-assembler-instructions-without-operands

This is a good tutorial for me.

Comment: Did you compile with optimization disabled or something?  With `register int reg_tmp;` perhaps?  That might explain why it's copying it to a call-preserved register and back for no reason (instead of store/reload to the stack like usual for anti-optimized debug builds.)

Comment: Yes, both actually this time. Wanted to see what I will get. I suppose I might get rid of reg_tmp, instead load it directly to r0.

Answer (score 3):

`%0` is the first (and in this case only) argument to the inline assembly block. The `=r` means it's an output in a general purpose register the compiler is free to choose and should map to the variable `reg_tmp`.  For further details see t[he documentation for inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#OutputOperands).

Your hand optimization is correct, but you can go further by leaving out the push and pop, since they cancel out.

It would also make it easier to read if you called `r14` by its other name `lr` (link register).  If you are generating code using GNU objdump, then try adding `-M reg-names-std` to get this automatically.

Comment: I haven't answered the other part of the question since it is covered it in the comments.  @Jester if you want to add your own answer or edit mine that would finish this off.

Comment: You can and should at least summarize things that were answered in detail in comments, although to be fair that's a basic inline-asm FAQ question.  If people answer in comments, it's usually because they don't want to take the time to write it as a full answer, or don't think it's worth posting as an answer (e.g. because it's probably a duplicate and/or the question is too specific to a special case.)  If you are going to answer, don't worry about leaving stuff out so people who answered in comments can get "credit".  If they wanted that, they could have posted an answer.

Comment: yea, thanks got it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree the answer belongs in an answer.  I was just allowing the person who made the answer in the comments time to make their own post before I copied what was said into mine.

Comment: The point of my comment was to explain that you shouldn't leave stuff out of your answer in order to do that in general.  And specifically not for Jester (or for me); we've been around long enough that we don't need the rep, and often write a quick help-the-OP response in comments without taking the time to write up a full answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: I do agree with Peter, but hey, still one can get all of the necessary info from the comments here and it helped me as the author most importantly and also we managed to give there links to necessary stuff to look at when someone will stumble upon it again. Also there are not that many comments on this right now so its still manageable.